# Bind checkbox.ischecked to boolean property?

Tags: c#, vb.net, xaml

Can someone smarter than me **please** help with what should be a simple coding task:  Binding .ischecked of a checkbox to a boolean property of an object?  I have created a simple project to mimic what I'm trying to do in a larger project for simple debug and demonstration.  I have a checkbox that when clicked sets a boolean property of my class object.  Another checkbox on the UI should update its checked state based on the T/F value of that boolean property.  What is wrong here and how to fix and just make it work? I "believe" the problem may be because I'm setting the property of a different object than what the checkbox.ischecked property is bound to (???).  Is that the problem, and if so how do I remedy that?  What code on the VB or XAML side needs to be implemented?

MainWindow.xaml.vb

```
Public Bools As New Boolean_Properties

Private Sub ckbx1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles ckbx1.Click
    If ckbx1.IsChecked Then
        Bools.Sta1Mode = True
    Else Bools.Sta1Mode = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Class Boolean_Properties

```
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
Private ModeSta1 As Boolean
Public Event ThePropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Property Sta1Mode As Boolean
    Get
        Return ModeSta1
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        ModeSta1 = value
        RaiseEvent ThePropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Sta1Mode"))
    End Set
End Property
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindBooleanProperty"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="217.032" Width="226.067">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:Boolean_Properties/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <CheckBox Content="Output" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="99.866,134.399,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="{Binding Sta1Mode, Mode=OneWay}">
        <CheckBox.DataContext>
            <local:Boolean_Properties/>
        </CheckBox.DataContext>
    </CheckBox>
    <CheckBox x:Name="ckbx1" Content=" Input" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="99.866,78.932,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: `Public Event ThePropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChange` looks really suspicious. The event is supposed to be called `PropertyChanged`. Did you try it without the alias?

Comment: ??  Isn't that how I have it?  "Public Event ThePropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use WPF Data Binding:
Instead of changing it using `if`, just bind the XAML interface and change the properties on the class.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Class1
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private _ModeSta1 As Boolean
    Property ModeSta1 As Boolean
        Get
            Return _ModeSta1
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _ModeSta1 = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(NameOf(ModeSta1)))
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Change the CheckBox to just Bind to the `ModeSta1` property

```
<CheckBox x:Name="ckbx1" 
    Content=" Input" 
    Margin="99.866,78.932,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    IsChecked="{Binding Path=ModeSta1, Mode=TwoWay}" 
/>
```

When the value of `ModeSta1` is changed, the User Interface is updated, and if user clicks the checkbox, the `ModeSta1` value is changed as well.

```
    Dim c = New Class1
    DataContext = c
    ' You can change the property and this change will be visible on the UI
    c.ModeSta1 = True
```

[image: CheckBox]

Comment: Got it.....finally.  To put it short, your last line of code where you are setting the Datacontext in code was the answer.  That is what was missing from my code and why it wasn't working.  So inside the ckbx1.Click event sub, I simply needed to add this simple line of code:  DataContex = Bools.  This makes the object "Bools" available for binding.

Comment: I am happy to help. Yes, I use it alot in this way. Works well. I almost never manipulate the UI directly, it is easier to manipulate the Binded object in memory.